# Grub fix after uninstall ubuntu dual boot windows 10

Tags: grub2, windows-10

After deleting Ubuntu partition and restarting window I cannot access my windows 10
I have motherboard h97-gmaing 
Can any one help me

Comment: That motherboard is UEFI. So did you install Windows in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? If BIOS, just run Windows repairs from your Windows repair disk. If UEFI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi